# Parsing time from camera exif info to wordpress time

Tags: wordpress

I don't know any coding at all, and would appreciate some help with this. I'm trying to have my camera exif info displayed in the wordpress media attachment page and having problems showing the capture date in regular wordpress format.

I'm using the code from here: https://havecamerawilltravel.com/notes/?wordpress%2Fwordpress_image_exif_metadata_media_library

It works well, except that the date is displayed in UNIX format. Would really appreciate help on how to have date from 'created_timestamp' displayed in regular format. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the filter function you are using from the mentioned article iterates over Exif metadata. I you want to format the `created_timestamp` metadata value, I would suggest the following addition to the `foreach` loop :

```php
foreach ($exif_data as $key => $value) {
    $exif = $metadata[$key];

    // Add the following condition
    if ($key === "created_timestamp") {
        $exif = date_i18n( get_option('date_format'), $exif );
    }

    $form_fields[$key] = array(
        'value' => $exif ? $exif : '',
        'label' => __($value) ,
        'input' => 'html',
        'html' => "<input type='text' class='text' readonly='readonly' name='attachments[$post->ID][$exif]' value='" . $exif . "' /><br />"
    );
}
```

**Explanation**

If the `$key` variable corresponds to `created_timestamp`, format the `$exif` data to Wordpress date_format option.

I hope it works, I could not this it myself!

Comment: You are welcomed, please accept my answer if you appreciate the help!